# Not able to edit npm config file manually

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, proxy, angular-cli

I am getting the following error while creating a new Angular project using Angular CLI.

`ng new <project-name>`

> npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for http://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ECONNRESET: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasmine failed, reason: socket hang up
>
> npm WARN registry Using stale package data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
>
> npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/jsesc failed, reason: socket hang up
>
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
>
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>
> npm ERR! network
>
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-01-23T15_11_33_289Z-debug.log
>
> Package install failed, see above.
>
> Package install failed, see above.

This could be because I am behind a corporate proxy. So I tried editing npm config file.

I used `npm config set proxy http://proxyhostname:proxyport` and `npm config set https-proxy http://proxyhostname:proxyport`.

But still, I was facing the same issue. When I opened the npm config file using `npm config edit`, I realised that the above commands for proxy settings are just adding two lines at the top of the npm config file but below it still has `proxy=null` and `https-proxy=null`. So I tried editing the file manually. Changed `proxy=null` to `proxy=http://proxyhostname:proxyport` and `https-proxy=null` to `https-proxy=http://proxyhostname:proxyport`. I didn't get any error while saving it but when I opened the file again with `npm config edit` I see that my manual changes are not present. Is there any step that I am missing to manually change the npm config file? Also, suggest if there is a different solution to the problem (mentioned above) I am facing.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue and below comments didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the terminal and write:

```sh
npm config edit
```

Then edit these lines, (adding comments with ";"):

```
;proxy=http://proxyhostname:proxyport
;https-proxy=http://proxyhostname:proxyport
```

Answer (score 0):

I think - your default editor is **vi**, just type `:wq` and press Enter(As you can see at the screen below), this command will save the file and exit from editor.
[image]